# Unable to mark a entity type as Regex in dialogflow

Tags: regex, dialogflow-es

I want to create a custom entity that will recognise all email addresses.

So I created a entity, gave in a regex expression, marked the 'Regex'check box and when I save it, the regex option gets automatically unchecked.
Below is the regex:
`/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/`
[image: unable to check entity as regex]

I think its not an issue with the regex, because I am not able to mark the entity with even the simplest regex `/^[a-z]$/`

Comment: This is strange since I can set it as an entity. The check box does not get cleared.

Comment: Apart from keying in the regex and checking the Regexp entity on, is there anything else that needs to be done? Like check any other options or something

Comment: Try without `/` chars on both ends.

Comment: that doesn't work! :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you are able to check entities as regexp, can you switch it to RAW Mode and show me a glimse of how the json structure looks like?

Comment: `[
    {
        "value": "^(([^<>()\\[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@\"]+(\\.[^<>()\\[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$",
        "synonyms": [
            "^(([^<>()\\[\\]\\\\.,",
            ":\\s@\"]+(\\.[^<>()\\[\\]\\\\.,",
            ":\\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$"
        ]
    }
]`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use the forward slashes at the beginning and end. Next, check "Define synonyms" box, then check the "Regexp entity" box. Then Save.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. Is it a bug that I need to tick the synonyms box?